# Spring boot MessageDispatcherServlet overriding DispatcherServlet. how to skip overriding and register both DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

in a single application, I m trying to use soap as well as rest web service. and each servlet is given different URI, below is the code of config class.

***The question is: only soap service URL is working fine but for the rest on getting 405 error.***

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean RsRegistrationBean(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet,"/rest/*");
    }

 @Bean
 public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(
      ApplicationContext context) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
    messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(messageDispatcherServlet,"/");
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the config and configure the paths through `application.properties`  both are autoconfigured as of Spring Boot 1.4. Also 405 means method not allowed, so make sure you have the proper method in your controller and that you are issuing the proper request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `WebServiceConfig` class, as both are auto-configured by Spring Boot already (as of Spring Boot 1.4). Add the following to your `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/rest
spring.webservices.path=/
```

Now you leverage the Spring Boot proivded infrastructure instead of fighting with it.

Comment: I try with above property but  I am geeting  "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found", for rest as well as soap.

Comment: You are using the proper starters?

Comment: with the above config, class soap is working fine but rest throw this exception Servlet.service() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] threw exception

com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Comment: This could be due to the `/` mapping as that is basically a catch-all. Your rest is correctly being send to `/rest/what-ever-you-have-here`? Which Spring Boot version are you using? As `spring.mvc.servlet.path` is for Spring Boot 2.x.

Comment: Then it should work. Make sure you don't have `@EnableWS` and/or `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables parts of the autoconfiguration. Please include the logging you get (with your config and with the proposed change!) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Spring Offical Doc: Wiring up Spring-WS in a DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d5e908)

This code does what you want it to do.

```
@EnableWs

@Configuration

public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(
          ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(messageDispatcherServlet,"/");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter controllerHandlerAdapter() {
      return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```